# PYthon pywinauto: how to code to detect if a extra screen appear, click OK, else move on to the next line of code

Tags: python, pywinauto

I am learning to use pywinauto to Automate data entry.

When i login, there's a chance an extra pop up window will appear (50-50) and i need to click "OK" button to continue.

So on my script i can find the button, but how do i tell me script to skip it if the pop up did not appear.

my Code:

#Enter User ID

app = Application(backend='uia').connect(title='SYSPRO')
sysproId = app.SYSPRO.child_window(auto_id="2", control_type="ComboBox").wrapper_object()
sysproId.type_keys("MYUSERID")

#Enter Password

sysproPw = app.SYSPRO.child_window(auto_id="3", control_type="Edit").wrapper_object()
sysproPw.type_keys("MYPASSWORD")

#Click Login

sysproLogin = app.SYSPRO.child_window(title="Login", auto_id="6", control_type="Button").wrapper_object()
sysproLogin.click_input()

#The 50-50 popup warning windows, which i need to click OK

sysproContinue = app.SYSPRO.child_window(title="OK", auto_id="CommandButton_1", control_type="Button").wrapper_object()
sysproContinue.click_input()

Continue to interface with nenu, etc etc

Answer (score 0):

To handle the situation where the pop-up window may or may not appear, you can use a try...except block to handle any potential exceptions that may occur when attempting to click the "OK" button. If the pop-up doesn't appear, the script will continue without any issues.

```
app = Application(backend='uia').connect(title='SYSPRO')

# Enter User ID
sysproId = app.SYSPRO.child_window(auto_id="2", control_type="ComboBox").wrapper_object()
sysproId.type_keys("MYUSERID")

# Enter Password
sysproPw = app.SYSPRO.child_window(auto_id="3", control_type="Edit").wrapper_object()
sysproPw.type_keys("MYPASSWORD")

# Click Login
sysproLogin = app.SYSPRO.child_window(title="Login", auto_id="6", control_type="Button").wrapper_object()
sysproLogin.click_input()

# Try to handle the pop-up window
try:
    sysproContinue = app.SYSPRO.child_window(title="OK", auto_id="CommandButton_1", control_type="Button").wrapper_object()
    sysproContinue.click_input()
except Exception as e:
    # Handle the case where the pop-up didn't appear
    print("Pop-up window did not appear:", e)

# Continue to interface with the menu, etc.
```